# How to group IList<T> using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, ilist

```
public static IList<string> GetAttribute_1(ModelContainer context, long productcatid)
{
    var query = from product in context.Products
                where product.ProductCategory_Id == productcatid
                select product.Attribute_1;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

how do i group by  product.Attribute_1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping can be done by using the group by linq operator.

The syntax would be something like:

```
var query = from product in context.Products
                        where product.ProductCategory_Id == productcatid
                        group product by prodyct.Attribute_1 into g
                        select new { Attribute_1 = g.Key, Products = g };
```

[Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) you can find Linq samples for grouping.

But I suppose you want all the unqiue Attribute_1 properties returned from your function?

You could then use the [Distinct](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) operator. That will fiter your list of Attribute_1 strings to contain only unique values.

Answer (score 1):

```
from product in context.Products
where product.ProductCategory_Id == productcatid
group product by product.Attribute_1 into g
select g;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
group product by product.Attribute_1 into g
```

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/GroupByOperator.ashx